# Is there a way to "undefine" an instance method to reveal the method defined in a prototype?

Tags: javascript, ruby, oop, function, prototype

I'm trying to wrap my head around javascript prototypes, and started to wonder if there is a way to remove/undefine an instance method defined on an object, so the method in the prototype would be called. So in the following

```
/* javascript */
function Foo () {};
Foo.prototype.myMethod = function() {alert('foo')};

var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

foo1.myMethod = function () {alert('foo changed for instance')};
Foo.prototype.myMethod = function () {alert('foo changed in prototype')};

foo1.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed for instance'
foo2.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed in prototype'
```

Is there a way to remove `myMethod` from instance `foo1`, so that calling `foo1.myMethod();` would call the method defined in the prototype and alert "*foo changed in prototype*"?

I guess I'm after something akin to removing a method from singleton class in Ruby, like:

```
# ruby
class Foo
  def myMethod
    puts "foo"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.myMethod # => foo

# make singleton class, re-define myMethod for this instance
def f.myMethod
  puts "bar"
end
f.myMethod # => bar

# remove method from singleton class
class << f
  remove_method :myMethod
end
f.myMethod # => foo
```

I'm asking out of sheer interest, so bonus points for practical use cases for this..

Comment: see http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete it

```
function Foo () {};
Foo.prototype.myMethod = function() {alert('foo')};

var foo1 = new Foo();
var foo2 = new Foo();

foo1.myMethod = function () {alert('foo changed for instance')};
Foo.prototype.myMethod = function () {alert('foo changed in prototype')};

foo1.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed for instance'
foo2.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed in prototype'


// deleting the unwanted method
delete foo1.myMethod;

foo1.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed in prototype'
foo2.myMethod(); // alerts 'foo changed in prototype'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/special_operators/delete_operator):

> The `delete` operator deletes a property of an object, or an element at a specified index in an array.

```
delete foo1['myMethod'];
```

It is the only way to remove properties of an object. A practical use case would be to remove entries from a *hash table*, which is implemented by using an object.